Rearranging terms of polynomials according to the constant coefficients
I have some polynomials on three variables and I want to gather terms with the same coefficients. For example
4 x^2 y^2 + 8 x^2 y z + 8 x y^2 z + 4 x^2 z^2 + 8 x y z^2 + 4 y^2 z^2

should be rearranged in the form:
4 (x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + x^2 z^2 )+ 8 ( x^2 y z +  x y^2 z +  x y z^2 )

Q1: I don't see how I can do this with Collect. Is it possible to do this?
Q2: Ideally I would also like to further simplify any common factors, so in the previous example a factor $x y z$ could be factored out of the brackets. The expression after manipulation should look like
4 (x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + x^2 z^2 )+ 8 x y z (x + y + z)


CoefficientRules can be used to collect monomials with the same coefficients. How about something like this?
Clear["Global`*"];
myCollect[f_, vars_] := 
  Total[#[[1, 2]]*
      Factor[Total[Inner[Power, vars, #[[1]], Times] & /@ #]] & /@ 
    GatherBy[CoefficientRules[f, vars], Last]];

f = 4 x^2 y^2 + 8 x^2 y z + 8 x y^2 z + 4 x^2 z^2 + 8 x y z^2 + 4 y^2 z^2;

myCollect[f, {x, y, z}]

(* 8 x y z (x+y+z)+4 (x^2 y^2+x^2 z^2+y^2 z^2) *)


A slight variation,
Using CoefficientRules:
expr = 4 x^2 y^2 + 8 x^2 y z + 8 x y^2 z + 4 x^2 z^2 + 8 x y z^2 + 
  4 y^2 z^2
CoefficientRules[expr] // 
    GatherBy[#, ContainsNone[First@#1, {1}] &] & // 
   FromCoefficientRules[#, {x, y, z}] & // Factor // Apply[Plus]


$4 \left(x^2 y^2+x^2 z^2+y^2 z^2\right)+8 x y z (x+y+z)$

pol = 4 x^2 y^2 + 8 x^2 y z + 8 x y^2 z + 4 x^2 z^2 + 8 x y z^2 + 4 y^2 z^2;


Using MonomialList:
f = Total@Map[Times @@ {First@#[[1]], Factor@Total@#[[2]]} &@*Map[Union]@*
    Thread]@GatherBy[{#1, Times @@ {##2}} & @@@ 
    List @@@ MonomialList[#1, #2], First] &;

f[pol, {x, y, z}] // TeXForm


$4 \left(x^2 y^2+x^2 z^2+y^2 z^2\right)+8 x y z (x+y+z)$

